MUI v5 ItemTree2 - How can I change the background of the selected item?
Using the same example from react-tree-view headless API from https://mui.com/x/react-tree-view/rich-tree-view/customization/#headless-api I can not change the background color of the selected item.
My codesandbox is here
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/condescending-merkle-5pk7wt?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.js%3A39%2C16
I unsuccessfully tried to customize the context with this code. Any recommendations?
const CustomTreeItemContent = styled(TreeItem2Content)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.Mui-focused, &.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected.Mui-focused`]: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: "white",
  },
}));

